# Could not build wheels for pyarrow

Tags: python, streamlit, pyarrow

This issue occurred when I install streamlit.
I had also tried to install "pyarrow" separately.
But the same error occurred.
Both Window and Python are 64bit.
Can anyone please help me with this Issue? Thank you in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLOwo.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8oZb.png)

Also tried to install pyproject.toml.

Comment: Can you share what version of Python are you using and what version of pyarrow are you trying to install? Thanks!

Comment: Always include the full error message as text in your question. This makes it serachable and accessible to people using assistive technologies such as screenreaders.

Comment: Hello Sir @raulcumplido 
python version is 3.11,
Actually I want to install streamlit.
May pyarrow be the dependency of steamlit.
I also tried to install pyarrow 8.0,9.0 separately.
But same error showing as shown in attached screenshots Sir!

Comment: well noted Sir @cafce25

Comment: Well you should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74532185/edit) your post and replace the images with text instead then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pyarrow wheels are not available for Python3.11 on PyPi yet. There is a minor pyarrow release 10.0.1 being voted at the moment that should be released soon. See this thread for the release approval:

https://lists.apache.org/thread/rlkrj9lnfmwgn7kq8hvmzf06l5z6w30k

And this thread for asking for the 10.0.1 release to add pyarrow wheels for Python 3.11:

https://lists.apache.org/thread/xrlztoz8no289rt6kr6qz52b8yjr3mob

Once the release is approved and published the pyarrow team will publish the new wheels to PyPi.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Sir!
Now I've downgrade python to 3.10 and reinstall streamlit's latest version and it works well.